# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() and SUM()

Tags: mysql-workbench

For example, I have the following table:

```
id     type         credit
1      loan1        300
2      loan1        200
3      loan2        500  
4      loan2        300
5      allowance1   400
6      allowance2   300
```

I want to display them in a single row like this

```
id          loan
1    loan1: 500, loan2: 800
```

so far, I have the following query which displays them in a single row

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type LIKE 'loan%' THEN concat(type, ': ', credit) ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ', ') as loan
```

output:

```
id                 loan
1    loan1: 300, loan1: 200, loan2: 500, loan2: 300
```

How do I display only distinct types and sum their credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minutes of googling would have provided this [article](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-sum-with-group-by.php)

```
SELECT id, type, SUM(credit)
FROM table
GROUP BY type;
```

Group by will group all equal types together. If you just want to get the distinct type use SELECT DISTINCT type from table